# FeedBurner Subscriber Counter?

Tags: php, feed, feedburner

I am looking for a PHP script that will simply display xxx subscribers who has subscribed to my feedburner feed.

I looked on Google but the ones I did find either did not work as they are old scripts or are overly complex.

Does anyone know where I can get a simple script that would display how many feedburner subscribers I have or anyone have a script they would like to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Feedburner Awareness API](http://code.google.com/apis/feedburner/awareness_api.html). For instance you can retrieve the URL [feedburner.google.com/api/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri=http://feeds.feedburner.com/phpclassesblog-xml](http://feedburner.google.com/api/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri=http://feeds.feedburner.com/phpclassesblog-xml) and then parse the returned XML to extract the relevant statistics.